# Unable to install notion-py module on Pythonista 3 using StaSh

Tags: python-3.x, pythonista

> I was trying to install notion-py on my phone to automate some tasks with iOS Shortcuts. I used Pythonista3, StaSh and typed 'pip install notion'. And it's not working as down below... is there any way that I could run notion-py module on my phone?

**[~/Documents]$ pip install notion**
Querying PyPI ...
Downloading package ...
Opening:  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/d5/2b184f608998cda08cc2862d7b4801f6e337490da2082b60aac04b287be4/notion-0.0.25-py3-none-any.whl

Save as: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C8ADF3B3-7229-4DBA-AF50-0585EB310D70/tmp//notion-0.0.25-py3-none-any.whl (39981 bytes)
[====================] 100.00% | 39.0KiB
Installing wheel: notion-0.0.25-py3-none-any.whl...
Package installed: notion
Dependency already bundled in distribution: requests
Installing dependency: commonmark (required by: notion)
Querying PyPI ...
Downloading package ...
Opening:
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/92/dfd892312d822f36c55366118b95d914e5f16de11044a27cf10a7d71bbbf/commonmark-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Save as: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C8ADF3B3-7229-4DBA-AF50-0585EB310D70/tmp//commonmark-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51068 bytes)
[====================] 100.00% | 49.9KiB
Installing wheel: commonmark-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl...
Package installed: commonmark
Installing dependency: bs4 (required by: notion)
Querying PyPI ...
Downloading package ...
Opening:
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/ed/7e8b97591f6f456174139ec089c769f89a94a1a4025fe967691de971f314/bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz

Save as: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C8ADF3B3-7229-4DBA-AF50-0585EB310D70/tmp//bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz (1121 bytes)
[====================] 100.00% | 1.1KiB
Extracting archive file ...
Archive extracted.
Running setup file ...
PipError('failed to find packages or py_modules arguments in setup call',)
Failed to run setup.py
Fall back to directory guessing ...
**Error: Cannot locate packages. Manual installation required.**

Answer (score 1):

Trying to install bs4 fails because BeautifulSoup is already included in Pythonista and not allowed to be overwritten.

If you ignore this error, there are other dependencies that will have trouble installing – I encountered at least ”slugify”. It is likely possible to install these by hand, i.e. finding the package repository and copying the files to site-packages yourself. wget in stash works well for this purpose.

Good luck!